# Associating identified metabolites with particular organisms or metabolic pathways

Tags: r

I am new to programming, I am trying to associate a list of metabolites that I manage to identify with particular organisms or metabolic pathways, but I am unable to generate a code to help me. I use R.

Some people same me that is easier to do in Python, but I don't know how use it.

This is the code I use

```
getMetabolitePathways <- function(metabolite) {
  pathway_info <- keggGet("pathway", metabolite)
  if (length(pathway_info) == 0) {
    return("No pathway information available")
  }
  pathways <- lapply(pathway_info, function(pathway) {
    paste(pathway$NAME, "-", pathway$ID)
  })
  return(unlist(pathways))
}
metabolite_pathways <- lapply(metabolites, getMetabolitePathways)
for (i in seq_along(metabolites)) {
  cat("Metabolite:", metabolites[i], "\n")
  cat("Pathways:\n")
  if (length(metabolite_pathways[[i]]) == 0) {
    cat("No pathway information available\n")
  } else {
    cat(paste(metabolite_pathways[[i]], collapse = "\n"), "\n")
  }
  cat("\n")
```

Comment: Can you actually load the necessary package (check result of `library(KEGGREST)`) - if not, please see here for installation procedure: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/KEGGREST.html